# can't get my code to to spawn a image within the dimensions of another image. using LibGDX

Tags: java, image, libgdx

Hi I have setup 2 rectangles
rectangle 1 and rectangle 2

I want to spawn a image between the current X + the width position of the first image.

but i cannot seem to get this to worth as it throws an error.
error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.inspirednotion.thing.Thing.<init>(Thing.java:65)
at com.inspirednotion.thing.MainThing.create(MainThing.java:18)
at    com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:144)
at    com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:131)
AL lib: ReleaseALC: 1 device not closed
```

This is the code i am using:

```
package com.inspirednotion.thing;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.TimeUtils;

public class Thing implements Screen {

MainThing g;
public OrthographicCamera cam;
public SpriteBatch batch;
public Texture t;
public TextureRegion tR;

public Texture tt;
public TextureRegion ttR;

public Texture cloud;
public TextureRegion cloudR;

Array<Rectangle> raindrops;
long lastDropTime;

Rectangle cloudRec;

Texture rainDrop;
TextureRegion rainDropR;

Rectangle water;

Random rand;

float moveY;

public Thing(MainThing g){
    this.g=g;
    cam = new OrthographicCamera(480,800);
    cam.position.set(480/2, 800/2, 0);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    t = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bg.png"));
    tR = new TextureRegion(t,0,0,480,700);

    tt = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bgCloud.png"));
    ttR = new TextureRegion(tt,0,0,480,350);

    cloud = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("cloud.png"));
    cloudR = new TextureRegion(cloud,0,0,256,140);

    rainDrop = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("RainDrop.png"));

    rand = new Random();

    moveY = 0;


    raindrops = new Array<Rectangle>();
    spawnRaindrop();

    cloudRec = new Rectangle();
    cloudRec.x = cam.viewportWidth /2 - 256 / 2;
    cloudRec.y = 600;
    cloudRec.height = 140;
    cloudRec.width = 256;

    water = new Rectangle();
    water.x = 0;
    water.y = -700;
    water.width = 480;
    water.height = 700;


}


private void spawnRaindrop() {
      Rectangle raindrop = new Rectangle();
      raindrop.x = MathUtils.random(cloudRec.x, cloudRec.x + cloudRec.width);
      raindrop.y = 510;
      raindrop.width = 64;
      raindrop.height = 64;
      raindrops.add(raindrop);
      lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
   }






@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, .05f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    cam.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(ttR,0,450,480,350);
    batch.end();

    batch.begin();
    if(moveY < cam.viewportHeight -200){
        water.y += 10  * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }else
    {
        moveY = 0;
    }
    batch.draw(tR, water.x, moveY + water.y , water.width, water.height);
    /*batch.draw(tR, 0, moveY -700,cam.viewportWidth, cam.viewportHeight);*/
    batch.end();

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(cloudR, cloudRec.x, cloudRec.y, cloudRec.width,       cloudRec.height);
    batch.end();

    batch.begin();
    for(Rectangle raindrop: raindrops) {
         batch.draw(rainDrop, raindrop.x , raindrop.y);
      }
    batch.end();

    if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) spawnRaindrop();

     Iterator<Rectangle> iter = raindrops.iterator();
      while(iter.hasNext()) {
         Rectangle raindrop = iter.next();
        //this effects the speed of downward movement
         raindrop.y -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(raindrop.y < water.y+680) iter.remove();
       // if(raindrop.overlaps(water)) {
           // dropSound.play();
          //  iter.remove();
        }}








@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: When you asked this question on the LibGDX forum, there was no mention of an exception. That exception appears to have nothing to do with the question, so I think the title of your question is confused with the task you are trying to accomplish, as opposed to the specifics of the exception. Furthermore, the code you included doesn't match up with the exception line number in any way that could cause a NullPointerException.

Comment: Sorry for not being cle3ar on the LibGDX forum.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate your cloudRec **before** calling `spawnRaindrop()`. That'd be the cause of your NullPointerException, because you are trying to use cloudRec in the `spawnRaindrop()` method..

Comment: sorry to be 'fresh fish' but newbie to this could you explain
" instantiate your cloudRec before calling spawnRaindrop()"
I don't understand what you mean by this.. thanks Daniel

Comment: `spawnRaindrop()` has to be called after you create and set the properties of cloudRec

Comment: Who is the dude, biggest error on my behalf but will not forget it.
Many Thanks for your time.
Best Daniel

Comment: Sweet glad it helped. If you'd be so kind as to mark this as answered that'd be awesome.